# How do I reverse the cd command in the Terminal on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal

I am beginning to learn ruby and was following the instructions of one video to access the desktop through the -ls command in the terminal. Now, I would like to get out of the desktop in the terminal and don't know how. I know, I know I am a total noob... but can someone please help. Thanks. BTW the command I wrote was:

```
   my-iMac~ me$ cd Desktop/
   my-iMac:Desktop samuel$ ls
```

Comment: Do you want to go home? Just type `cd`

Comment: You can type: `cd ..` to go up one directory.

Comment: Got it... thanks a lot. I feel foolish, part of learning I guess

Comment: Use `cd -` to go the previous directory

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Where would you like to go?

Go home: `cd` or `cd ~`
Go to the previous working directory: `cd $OLDPWD`
Go to parent of the current directory: `cd ..`
Go to any directory you want: `cd /path/to/directory`

Comment: `cd -` is fewer keystrokes than `cd $OLDPWD`

Comment: `cd -` I wish I knew that one years ago *(yes, I know this isn't really allowed)*

Comment: if cd - gives error like "-bash: cd: OLDPWD not set" then just export OLDPWD in your ~/.bash_profile file and source it.

Answer (score 11):

`cd ..` will take you back up 1 level.

Comment: Scott bestAnswer

Answer (score 0):

for windows, you can open up the file explorer copy path then in your command prompt type "cd" then paste path. Your command prompt should now default to that path. (you can also type the entire path)

```
cd C:\Users\username\Documents\Folder
```